# Simple Spring REST test throws HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have set up a simple Spring REST method in a class which should just return the text that was sent to it in a POST request as a response. My method in class MyService.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my/url", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> myMethod(@RequestBody final String body) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(body, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I have a unit test which uses Spring's MockMvc to test the method:

```
@Autowired
private MyService service;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = standaloneSetup(service).build();
}

@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception {
    Assert.assertNotNull(service); // Class has been instantiated

    final String content = "Hello world";
    final String url = "/my/url";

    final MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post(url) //
            .content(content) //
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)) //
            .andExpect(status().isOk()) //
            .andReturn();
}
```

The test fails with a message "Status expected:<200> but was:<415>" on the perform() line of the unit test. In the console, I can see this message:

Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'null' not supported

415 is a "content not supported" error.

Spring version 4.1.7.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding the content type by mockMvc.perform(post(url).contentType(MediaType.Text_PLAIN_VALUE)......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Missing the content type when performing the POST. I added this to the test and it worked successfully:

```
.header("Content-Type", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
```